# flask : how to architect the project with multiple apps?

Tags: python, flask

Lets say I want to build a project Facebook

I need a project structure like

```
facebook/
         __init__.py
         feed/
             __init__.py
             models.py
             business.py
             views.py
         chat/
             __init__.py
             models.py
             business.py
             views.py
         games/
             __init__.py
             models.py
             business.py
             views.py
         common/
             common.py

         runserver.py
```

How can I structure this well so that when I run

```
python facebook/runserver.py
```

It loads views from all my apps internally?
I want to keep this structure because extending the project further is more natural way

I am trying to follow their [advice](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/patterns/packages/), but don't really understand where I need to write

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)
```

and how to import all views from all apps at one place, please help

If lets say I write the above code in `facebook/__init__.py`, then how in `facebook/feed/views.py`, I can do

```
from facebook import app
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I have tried blueprints and came up with a solution which works for me, let me know if you have other ideas.

**Project Structure**

```
facebook/
        runserver.py
        feed/
            __init__.py
            views.py
        chat/
            __init__.py
            views.py
```

**Code**

```
# create blueprint in feed/__init__.py
from flask import Blueprint

feed = Blueprint('feed', __name__)
import views

# create blueprint in chat/__init__.py
from flask import Blueprint

chat = Blueprint('chat', __name__)
import views

# add views (endpoints) in feed/views.py
from . import feed

@feed.route('/feed')
def feed():
    return 'feed'

# add views (endpoints) in chat/views.py
from . import chat

@chat.route('/chat')
def chat():
    return 'chat'

# register blueprint and start flask app
from flask import Flask
from feed import feed
from chat import chat

app = Flask(__name__)
app.register_blueprint(feed)
app.register_blueprint(chat)
app.run(debug=True)
```

**In Action**

```
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/
# Hit Urls
http://127.0.0.1:5000/feed # output feed
http://127.0.0.1:5000/chat # output chat
```

Comment: Yes, that worked. I've added the code from the link to the answer since link-only answers are not preferred (see: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259)

Comment: what happens if chat app crashes? Is feed still available?

Answer (score 23):

Use [blueprints](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/blueprints/). Each one of your sub-applications should be a blueprint, and you load every one of them inside your main init file.

Answering your second question

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)
```

You should put this into `facebook/__init__.py`

BTW, my `runserver.py` and `settings.py` always resides one level under `facebook/`.

Like this:

```
facebook/
         __init__.py
         feed/
             __init__.py
             models.py
             business.py
             views.py
         chat/
             __init__.py
             models.py
             business.py
             views.py
         games/
             __init__.py
             models.py
             business.py
             views.py
         common/
             common.py

runserver.py
settings.py
```

Content of `runserver.py`:

```
from facebook import app
app.run()
```

I suppose the content of `settings.py` should not be explained.

Content of `facebook/__init__.py`:

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_object('settings')
from blog.views import blog #blog is blueprint, I prefer to init them inside views.py file
app.register_blueprint(blog,url_prefix="/blog")
```

Comment: Thanks!, I have sorted it other way, please see my answer